# Understand deadlock graph (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I get this deadlock graph:

[image: deadlock graph]

Query on the right is a simple `UPDATE` of one row. I understand that it acquired exclusive lock on the key (because it's clustered index it's basically a way of lock on the row) and also need intent lock to prevent other transaction to take locks on the page.

Query on the left is a bit more complicated transaction with some `SELECT` and `UPDATE`. But as I understand the situation it wants to read the row changed by the query on the right but it already owns shared lock on the page where this row resides.

What I don't understand is when X lock on a row and IX lock on a page is needed to update a row, why it is possible to get X lock on the row when there is already S lock on the page. Shouldn't IX lock on the page be acquired first? And can I do something about it other then retry the transaction?

Comment: Looks like a bookmark lookup deadlock, which can usually be solved with `INCLUDE` columns. But we need to see the full deadlock XML, along with the table and index definitions, and please share the query plans of the two queries via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Also read about Row-Versioning which can eliminate the S locks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15  Also you can often resolve deadlocks by using manual application locks to serialize your transactions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Re "complicated transaction with some SELECT and UPDATE" - if you select data from same tables/records, which you update later, then use `updlock` hint in select statement. This may sometimes help, no guarantee of course.